# Generalization of ordered pairs - Halmos' "Naive Set Theory"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, set-theory

In Section 9 of Halmos' "Naive Set Theory" it is stated that given a family $\{X_a, X_b\}$ of subsets of some embedding set $E$, indexed by an unordered pair $\{a,b\}$ such that $a \neq b$, it is customary to identify the product of the family with the cartesian product $X_a \times X_b$. Then Halmos proceeds by stating that sets of ordered triples, quadruples, ... can be obtained analogously by starting from families indexed by unordered triples, quadruples, ... whose elements are all distinct.

Now, my question concerns the fact that order arises from the application of a function to an unordered pair. However that does not seem possible to me: why, for instance, don't we identify the previous product with $X_b \times X_a$? In fact there is nothing telling us that $a$ should come before $b$. I think that the statement should be rectified by using $\{\{a\}, \{a,b\}\}$ instead of $\{a,b\}$. However I am not completely sure of this and I would like some feedback on my reasoning!

---

As always, any comment or answer is appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: I tried reading the book but this part is quite over my head. From what I could puzzle out, it appears that you have misunderstood what a family is, and there is nothing about an embedding set $E$ in the book actually. The unordered pair appears to grab two or three or more indices which we then apply to get those sets. But I've upvoted and I'm following to see if a better solution comes along.

Comment: @SuzuHirose I know there is nothing like an “embedding set” is just an expression I use to say that there is a set including all the sets I am working with (so that for example empty intersection still makes sense)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All that really matters for an implementation or representation of ordered pairs is that $$(w,x)=(y,z)\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad w=y\text{ and }x=z\tag{1}$$

If we fix an *unordered* pair $P=\{a,b\}$ with $a\ne b$ and adopt the convention of representing a pair $(x,y)$ by the function $f_{x,y}$ on $P$ with $f_{x,y}(a)=x$ and $f_{x,y}(b)=y$, then this representation satisfies (1):
$$f_{w,x}=f_{y,z}\qquad\text{if and only if}\qquad w=y\text{ and }x=z$$
So we don't need an ordering relation on $P$ for this to work. However, this convention is arbitrary. We could just as well adopt the convention of representing a pair $(x,y)$ by the function $g_{x,y}$ on $P$ with $g_{x,y}(a)=y$ and $g_{x,y}(b)=x$, and this convention also satisfies (1).

The fact that we can choose either convention reflects the fact that there is a natural bijection between the cartesian products $X\times Y$ and $Y\times X$.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all in my opinion.

Comment: @SuzuHirose If that part of Halmos' book is over your head, as you indicated in another comment, then possibly my answer is also. But my answer intends to clarify (i) how a suitable notion of order can arise from functions defined on an unordered set and (ii) how an arbitrary choice is implicit in the convention and resulting identification. These are precisely the two things the OP was confused about.

Comment: I claim that this does not answer the question since your answer does not mention any of the constructions in Halmos's book such as families. At the right of the screen (if you are viewing this on computer rather than a phone) you can find various people asking and answering a very similar question to this one, and you can check for yourself that your answer does not address the core issues. In fact I probably should vote to close the question as a duplicate.

Comment: @SuzuHirose You seem to have missed in your attempted reading of Halmos that families are defined as functions. I'd consider that a core issue. :) Anyway, vote as you please.

Comment: It's possible that I have not understood your answer correctly, but re-reading Halmos I'm not certain of that. I will put some more time into this before responding further. I certainly won't downvote an answer without leaving a comment. Regarding my comment on voting, I realised after voting on this question that the original question was a duplicate of other questions, which is orthogonal to the issue of your answer.